# Submit a form with JQuery Ajax still displaying target page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use jQuery Ajax in my form to submit...

Here is the full code of the page:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['save'])) {
    print "<pre>";
    print_r($_POST);
    print "</pre>";
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>






<!-- TinyMCE -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "advanced",
        plugins : "safari,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,wordcount",

        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
        theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing : true,

        // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
        content_css : "css/content.css",

        // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
        template_external_list_url : "lists/template_list.js",
        external_link_list_url : "lists/link_list.js",
        external_image_list_url : "lists/image_list.js",
        media_external_list_url : "lists/media_list.js",

        // Replace values for the template plugin
        template_replace_values : {
            username : "Some User",
            staffid : "991234"
        }
    });
</script>
<!-- /TinyMCE -->

</head>
<body>

<form id="my_form" method="post" action="insert.php">
    <div>
        <h3>Edit Page</h3>



        <!-- Gets replaced with TinyMCE, remember HTML in a textarea should be encoded -->
        <div>
            <textarea id="elm1" name="elm1" rows="15" cols="80" style="width: 80%">
<?php
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'dev');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("my_db");
$query = "SELECT * FROM pages where id=1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$contents = $row['content'];
echo $contents;
?>
            </textarea>
        </div>

        <br />
        <input id="submit_page_changes" type="submit" name="save" value="Submit" />
        <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" />
    </div>
</form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#my_form').submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            alert($(this).serialize());
        });
    });
</script>



</body>
</html>
```

Basically I need it to submit using JQuery Ajax.

EDIT:

Here is the code from insert.php

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","dev");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("my_db");


$sql="UPDATE pages SET content=('$_POST[elm1]') WHERE id='1'";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";


$query = "SELECT * FROM pages where id=1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$contents = $row['content'];

echo $contents;

mysql_close($con)
?>
```

Comment: Is the script before or after the form? If it's before, then the element won't exist when the code is executed, and the event handler will never be bound. If that is the case, wrap everything between the `<script>` and `</script>` tags in `$(function() {...}`.

Comment: what is it displaying inside `alert($(this).serialize());` alert?

Comment: This is an example alert: elm1=%3Cp%3ETesting+123%3C%2Fp%3E++++++++++++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will do the trick :

```
$('#my_form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    $.post("insert.php", $("#my_form").serialize(), function (response) {
        //do something on success
    });

});
```

or try using below code to post data to backend:

```
$.post("insert.php", {'elm1' : $('#elm1').val()}, function (response) { 
    //do something on success
});
```

Since you are using tinyMCE for textarea #elm1 use:

```
$.post("insert.php", {'elm1' : tinyMCE.get('elm1').getContent()}, function (response) { 
    //do something on success
});
```

Comment: make sure that the url of the insert.php file is proper. is it hitting the insert.php page?

Comment: Added Full page source code as I still cannot get it to work...Tried all scripts

Comment: try 
`$.post("insert.php", {'elm1' : $('#elm1').val()}, function (response) {
        //do something on success
    });`

Comment: what is the error that you are getting? try alerting the response from the callback function of post

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8886/discussion-between-nemoy-and-satch3000)

Answer (score 3):

Satch,

First you need to insert the submit script inside a $(document).ready function like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#my_form").submit(function() {

            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'insert.php',
                contentType: "application/json",
                data:$(this).serialize(),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg);
                  },
                error: function(msg){
                    alert("Error" + msg);
                }
            });

          return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

You will also need to post the serialized data through the jquery ajax function like $.ajax.
I hope that this helps.

Comment: Good call... especially if the script is included on the page before the HTML element it is bound to (as the sample code above might suggest).

Comment: That's correct. The event.preventDefault() is not needed in this case since he is already returning false.

Comment: OK, this one doesn't got to insert.php of that's right...the problem is that it's not submitting the change (Not executing insert.php in other words), if it would save it would be perfect.

Comment: Satch, it is not executing because you are not actually "ajaxing" anything. Try my updated answer.

Comment: Added Full page source code as I still cannot get it to work...Tried all scripts

Comment: Satch, what is the complete path to the insert.php page? Make sure that the url variable in the ajax function has the correct path to the page.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using the `$.ajax` method

Comment: Tried this: $.ajax('#my_form').submit(function() {  ... but problem still there

Comment: @Satch3000 check my answer i have written the demo

Comment: Added Full page source code as I still cannot get it to work...Tried all scripts

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning false, try preventdefault:

```
<script>
$('#my_form').submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert($(this).serialize());
});
</script>
```

EDIT: To include Eduardo's tip above, here is a more extended answer:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="my_form" method="post" action="insert.php">
    <input type="submit" name="save" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#my_form').submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            alert($(this).serialize());
        });
    });
</script>
```

A couple of things to note:
- You should include the query library on top of the page (preferably the head)
- You should FIRST include the HTML, then the script that uses the HTML (otherwise the JS doesn't know about the element)
- If you have to add the JS above the HTML, use `$(document).ready()`, as it will make sure all HTML is part of the DOM before attaching any event handlers to it.
- If you already use jQuery on the page, the use `event.preventDefault();` is slightly safer than `return false;`.

Comment: Added Full page source code as I still cannot get it to work...Tried all scripts

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about "cannot get it to work" means?  What does work and what does not? Can you get a step by step description of what happens when you submit?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
type: 'post',
url: 'insert.php',
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
data:{'id':id}
dataType: "json",
beforeSend: function () {
//show wait
},
success: function (msg) {
    if (msg.d != null) {
    //result is obtained
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Still going to insert.php page :-/

Comment: @Satch3000 also use event.preventDefault() as suggested by steve

Comment: Added Full page source code as I still cannot get it to work...Tried all scripts

Comment: @Satch3000 I have tried a fiddle to check whether submit button take you to your php page or not it works fir sending useful information to your php page use data property. the fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/vzrcQ/

Comment: I can see you are getting the alert. On mine it's just not saving to the db. I've added the insert.php code too

Comment: @Satch3000 have you checked that you are getting correct text value and also how you are assigning value to data property in $.ajax call

Comment: The code is all there...I've added the full code for both files. Strange that the ajax doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**:   You can use $.ajax in that function so that it will post the data

Modify your code like:

```
<script>
$('input[name=save]').click(function(e)
{
  alert($('#my_form').serialize());
  return false; // You can also use e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Still going to insert.php page :-/

Comment: dont use .submit method and then check

Comment: Added Full page source code as I still cannot get it to work...Tried all scripts